# How to split string where spaces are?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I want to split string where the spaces are, and put it into an array. For example, if the str is "foo bar asdf" I want the array to be ["foo", "bar", "asdf"]. I know you can easily do that like so:

```
str = raw_input("Enter String")

cstr = ""
for char in str:
    if char == " ":
        print cstr
    else:
        cstr = cstr + char
```

But that outputs only the first word until the space, and it is quite bulky for something so simple. How can I do this simply?

Comment: Just do `str.split()`. See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split) for full syntax and explanation.

Comment: Also, avoid using `str` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin `str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `split` method on strings is for:

```
>>> "foo bar asdf".split(' ')
['foo', 'bar', 'asdf']
```

The argument is the string to split on, or you can just do `.split()` without an argument to split on any whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! This will you helpful. HAVE A CHECK!

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary: Where is his check?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Usage in your case would be something like:

```
 for cstr in mystr.split(' '):  #renamed 'str' to 'mystr'
     print cstr
```